# Node.js .toISOString() to Swift DateFormatter()

Tags: node.js, swift, isodate, dateformatter

I'm getting the date and time from a server using `.toISOString()` which returns `2018-09-30T10:36:39.165Z`.

I then want to convert this to a `Date()` in Swift so that I can manipulate it by adding an hour. I found a website saying the format for `.toISOString()` is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`.

I then set the format of the swift `DateFormatter()`:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"
```

However this does not seem to work as when I try to perform the conversion it fails:

```
guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: time) else {
    fatalError("ERROR: Date conversion failed due to mismatched format.")
}
```

I assume it's an issue with the format string I'm using but I can't find what it should be, any ideas?

Comment: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ" is definitely wrong – on which website did you find that? You find the complete list at http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns.

Comment: @MartinR I found it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString but I could be misinterpreting it.

Comment: Note that there is  a dedicated [NSISO8601DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter) in the Foundation library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `T` between `'`s:

```
let time = "2018-09-30T10:36:39.165Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: time)
```

Comment: You need to set the formatter's locale to "en_US_POSIX" when parsing fixed date format. As it is this might fail depending one the user device settings/locale.

Comment: Btw where withoutMilliseconds comes from ? you meant `from: time`

Comment: @LeoDabus withoutMilliseconds was from an earlier edit. What do you mean by "*this might fail*"?

Comment: The timestamp since 1970 is correct. The string describing that date could differ based on the locale/timezone, but as a Date, it is an unrelated TimeInterval/Double. In this case it is 1538303799.165